# size different in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm making a simple website.
i'm using chrome as default to check my site, and after i get to the result i want, i check the site with explorer and firefox BUT then i found out that the size of a div and it's position is not the same in different browsers(in IE9).

css file:

```
   body 
{
    height:1000px;
    width:inherit;

background-image: url('תמונות/BackGroundBig.jpg'); /* fallback */
background-image: url('תמונות/BackGroundBig.jpg'), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
background-image: url('תמונות/BackGroundBig.jpg'), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background-image: url('תמונות/BackGroundBig.jpg'), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* FF3.6+ */
background-image: url('תמונות/BackGroundBig.jpg'), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #00000); /* IE10 */
background-image: url('תמונות/BackGroundBig.jpg'), -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background-image: url('תמונות/BackGroundBig.jpg'), linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* W3C */ 

}

#Header
{
    width:inherit;
    height:225px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#Header img
{

    position:absolute;
    left:20.4em;
 }
```

html file:

```
 <div id="Header">
    <div class="headerDiv"></div>
    <img id="headerLogo" src="../תמונות/HeaderLOGO2.jpg" alt="" />
    <div  class="headerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

with this code i can't see a background image in IE9 and the size different of the objects i can see are very different in IE9 from chrome and firefox.

i want to know somthing:
do different browsers have different meaning to, lets say a div with a 100px width and a 200px height?

any adivce a link to an artical about it will be great!
(sorry for my english)

Comment: do u mean? <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">?

Comment: A transitional doctype can cause box model issues, which cause sizing differences between browsers. Consider using a strict doctype - `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**100px width, and 200px height are equal across all browsers.**
You'll be safe there.

Do take into consideration that you are using `em`, that is *equal to the current font-size* without specifying the actual font-size. You're leaving that interpretation for the browser.

```
body {
    font-size: 10px; /* this will make em cross-behave */
}
```

But browsers do have different implementations of paddings, margins and some other oddities. Even though the majority of CSS rules are supported equality cross-browser there are some peculiarities here and there.

You should try to test cross-browser as you develop to prevent a "how can this be" final result.

[Taking a look at **Quirksmode.org** is always a life-saver.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Chrome, Firefox and Safari you can test out of the box and a huge percentage of users already have the latest and greatest version. For IE you can use [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) that will help you see how different versions react to different CSS markups.

Comment: is there a document that list the changes?

Comment: @samy, there is, take a look into the edit where I added quirksmode.org.